# UI design in iOS, C#

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I am a new convert from C# and heavy UI interaction to iOS.
If anyone has worked in both technologies I hope you can help me with this question:
I have a View, in which I add a bottom view ( all through Interface Builder ). Now I need the bottom view to dock to bottom of theview it was added to, meaning whenever the parent view is resized ( as in increases in height ) the bottom view on that view should accordingly stay at the bottom , in Visual studio this is called docking, is there an equivalent for it in XCode interface builder? or even via code?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in IB, it's under the "ruler" icon. There is a Autoresizing section.
If you are using the newest tool, it could also be name Constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with IB, but programmatically you can achieve the docking effect you describe using the `autoresizingMask` property of a `UIView`, for example:

```
view.autoResizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, parentView.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
```

You might also want your docked view to expand horizontally when its parent view is stretched, in which case you'd bitwise OR another option to `autoResizingMask`:

```
view.autoResizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, parentView.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height, parentView.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
```